# Adding to request header?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlet-filters

Im using tomcat\spring security and in the test environment I need to add a parameter to my HEADER for selenium testing

What are my options for simluting this in my dev environment?

- Servlet-Filter
- Proxy
- Other feature in Spring or tomcat?

The issue with the filter is that I will have to ensure it is only on my dev environment, and the proxy is extra configuration

Comment: If you have a different tomcat for your test env and prod env, you can simply create a new servlet-filter, annotate it, build a jar, and put it in your test tomcat lib folder. If you have scanning for filters on in your web.xml, it will find your filter (from the jar in your tomcat lib) and instantiate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring profiles you could annotate that filter with `@Profile("dev")` and it will only be loaded when the `dev` profile is active. More info:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles